# Combining multiple rows to one

Tags: sql, function, db2, self-join, coalesce

I'm attempting to combine multiple names across rows to one column when the project_id matches.  I started with a self join but could not get it to work the way I wanted it to and I'm pretty certain there is a function or cte that can do this a lot easier.  Asking for direction.  Working with db2.

Here is what I have so far which doesnt work and is producing a -104 error.

```
  (

        SELECT 
                        DP.D_P_ID, DP.project_name,
                        DU2.NAME_LAST CONCAT ', ' CONCAT DU2.NAME_FIRST AS 
                        FROM Fact_table as FAT 
                        INNER JOIN D_P DP ON FAT.D_P_ID = DP.D_P_ID
                        INNER JOIN B_U_P BUP on DP.D_P = BUP.D_P_ID
                        INNER JOIN D_U DU2 ON BUP.D_U_ID = DU2.D_U_ID
                        INNER JOIN D_Date DD ON FAT.START_DATE_ID = DD.DATE_KEY
                        INNER JOIN D_A DA ON FAT.D_A_ID = DA.D_A_ID
                        WHERE  ((    (DD.DATE_VALUE >= '2013-01-01')
                                OR (DD.DATE_VALUE < '2014-01-01')
                                OR (DD.DATE_VALUE <= '2013-01-01')))
                                AND DA.M_NAME = 'Mandy'
                                AND BUP.USER_FLAG = 'Y'

                        GROUP BY  DP.D_P_ID, DP.project_name, DU2.NAME_LAST CONCAT ', ' CONCAT DU2.NAME_FIRST
                        ORDER BY DP.project_name 
             )  PI1      

                 join 

                        (
                                SELECT 
                        DP.D_P_ID, DP.project_name,
                        DU2.NAME_LAST CONCAT ', ' CONCAT DU2.NAME_FIRST AS 
                        FROM Fact_table as FAT 
                        INNER JOIN D_P DP ON FAT.D_P_ID = DP.D_P_ID
                        INNER JOIN B_U_P BUP on DP.D_P = BUP.D_P_ID
                        INNER JOIN D_U DU2 ON BUP.D_U_ID = DU2.D_U_ID
                        INNER JOIN D_Date DD ON FAT.START_DATE_ID = DD.DATE_KEY
                        INNER JOIN D_A DA ON FAT.D_A_ID = DA.D_A_ID
                        WHERE  ((    (DD.DATE_VALUE >= '2013-01-01')
                                OR (DD.DATE_VALUE < '2014-01-01')
                                OR (DD.DATE_VALUE <= '2013-01-01')))
                                AND DA.M_NAME = 'Mandy'
                                AND BUP.USER_FLAG = 'Y'

                        GROUP BY  DP.D_P_ID, DP.project_name, DU2.NAME_LAST CONCAT ', ' CONCAT DU2.NAME_FIRST
                        ORDER BY DP.project_name 
                        ) PI2 on PI1.d_p_id = PI2.d_p_id
```

Data example:
[image]

This is the result that I need:
[image]

Comment: What's your DB2 version and platform?

Comment: I'm using DbVisualizer with version number 9070500

Comment: DBVisualizer is the tool you are using to query the data, not the DB2 database the information is stored in. What version of DB2 is the database server running and what operating system? This information may help us give you the best answer for your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the outer select use something like

```
select d_p_id, project_name, listagg(admin, ',')
from (...)
group by d_p_id, project_name
```

The `listagg()` function, available in DB2 9.7 and later, aggregates by concatenation within a group, using the specified delimiter.